# disjunctional phrase not working in ansible conditional

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write something like this:

```
- name: get gui2 git contents
  git: repo={{ gui2_repository }} dest=/var/www/gui2 version={{ gui2_gitversion }}
  when: update_all or update_gui2
```

However, it still runs the above task, even if both `update_all` and `update_gui2` are false.

If I only use

```
- name: get gui2 git contents
  git: repo={{ gui2_repository }} dest=/var/www/gui2 version={{ gui2_gitversion }}
  when: update_all
```

(or `update_gui2` in the when above), it skips the task as it should.

Any idea how I should write a disjunctional logical phrase in an ansible conditinal?

Comment: Try with boolean conversion `when: update_all | bool or update_gui2 | bool`

Comment: Please post the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The information in the question is not sufficient to reproduce the problem. Voting to close.

Comment: @techraf see [gist](https://gist.github.com/berlic/2fd91e9925c66419d5d27b3a5111cbde)

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Oh, I see... I was too lazy to type `false` and used `no` .

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Thanks, your tip was spot on! If you put it in an answer, I will accept it! However, your gist does not seem to work for me, it skips all four tasks if I put false for var1 and var2 in group_vars/all :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the comment:

> Try with boolean conversion `when: update_all | bool or update_gui2 | bool`

This is because ansible-jinja template engine works a bit different for whole expression and for parts of it.

Comment: The engine works differently, but the reason was because variables were strings, not Boolean as incorrectly stated in the question ("*both `update_all` and `update_gui2` are false*").